# Boostrap Large Image - Fixed Position & Responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to have an image float to the right of the page which resizes in Large, and Medium screens, but vanishes in Small and Xtra Small screens.

I can make the image vanish using hidden-sm and hidden-xs in bootstrap, but im struggling to make the image (considering it's so large) float to the right of the page like the attached **non-responsive** picture.

Do I need to use Width: % to make this move? I tried this and this doesn't work well in terms of being responsive etc..

[Screenshot - non-responsive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpEe5.jpg)

Heres the HTML for the picture:

```
<!-- PICTURE -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-offset-md-9 col-md-3 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <div class="BackgroundImage center-block img-responsive"><img src="Pictures/Profile.png" alt="Background Image"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And heres the simple CSS i've got so far:

```
/* Background Image/Neil Photo */
.BackgroundImage {
    width: 190px;
}

.BackgroundImage img {
    z-index: -1;
    margin-bottom: -366%;
    display: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You must use "position" not "display" for fixed position and make the styles like this:**

```
.BackgroundImage {
    //width: 190px;
}

.BackgroundImage img {
    z-index: -1;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
```

However, you still have two other problems in your website that makes it look non-responsive:

**You need to remove:**

```
p { 
    width:110%; 
}
```

**You need to remove:**

```
footer { 
    margin-left:19%; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use the `vw` unit instead of `%`

`vw` sets the size of the element relative to **viewport-width**, regardless of anything else.

For example:

```
.BackgroundImage img {
    z-index: -1;
    margin-bottom: -366%;
    width: 50vw;
    display: fixed;
}
```

You can add the `right: 0` property to attach the image to the right of it's position reference.

```
.BackgroundImage img {
    z-index: -1;
    margin-bottom: -366%;
    width: 50vw;
    right: 0;
    display: fixed;
}
```

read more here:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

and check out compatibility for viewport units here:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: I tried entering in the following CSS:

.BackgroundImage img {
    z-index: -1;
    margin-bottom: -223%;
    right: 0;
    width: 35vw;

}

This doesn't actually move the picture at all despite inputting Right: 0;